# What's the difference between omelette/frittata/quiche?

Tags: eggs, language

What is the culinary difference between these dishes?
It seems to me that they are all egg dishes that are cooked with some fillings in them (onion/tomato/ham/cheese etc). Is quiche just a frittata in pastry?

Comment: Two almost identical foods can be called different if they come from different areas. I guess that is part of the explanation here.

Comment: You missed tortilla, which is far more like a frittata than a french omelette.

Comment: Hi. Welcome. I have a feeling you have done no research here at all. It would be better to look up some recipes to see the differences . . . these aren't the same thing at all.  And no, a quiche is not just a fritatta with pastry.  A quiche has a savoury egg custard filling.

Answer (score 4):

**Quiche** has a crust, while the other two do not.  But it’s also not stirred while cooking, so the texture is different, especially if you add any milk to it so it’s more of a custard.

There are multiple types of **omelette** (French, italian, Japanese), but in general they’re egg dishes that are cooked stovetop with fillings typically added after the egg has begun to set up.

**Frittata** is stirred as it’s cooked at the beginning, with the fillings often cooked first then the eggs added in, then put in the oven to finish.

And had been mentioned there’s also the Spanish **tortilla** in which the filling is cooked, then added to the beaten eggs, then put back to the pan, then flipped to finish cooking

I would also add the Italian **pizza rustica** which is an egg pie, so it’s quiche-like but also has a top crust.

And there’s a style of ‘egg roll’, which can be rather omelette like, in that it’s a thin crepe-like omelette that’s then wrapped around a filling.

… and then you start getting into various types of sweeter quiche-like dishes, like Italian cheesecake (aka ‘ricotta pie’) and custard pies